# FOSUserBundle: Success target after password reset

Tags: symfony, url-routing, fosuserbundle

After the user did reset his password using the password reset of FOSUserBundle, by default he is redirected to the FOSUserProfile.
I want to redirect to a different route.
Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It can be done by creating a resetting subscriber:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class PasswordResettingListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS => 'onPasswordResettingSuccess',
        ];
    }

    public function onPasswordResettingSuccess(FormEvent $event) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('homepage');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

And then registering it as a service with `kernel.event_subscriber` tag:

```
# src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme_user.password_resetting:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\PasswordResettingListener
        arguments: [ @router ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Note: This solution requires you to use the master version for FOS Userbundle.

You can achive a simmilar result by extending the reset controller and changing the getRedirectionUrl() method.

Comment: Note : Since Symfony 4, you don't need specify router argument in your service.yml.

Answer (score 23):

In case you are not using the FOS user profile view, there is an ugly yet simple way:

Add in your `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
fos_user_profile_show:
    path: /yourpath
```

Comment: You can also declare the route in your own controller with the name `fos_user_profile_show`, better than absolute url.

Comment: @LouTerrailloune there is no absolute url in above routing configuration. It might look like it but it aint